# Create a project template that retrieve references from a repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, t4, nuget

I'm trying to create a project template that loads a couple of projects and adds a reference to a dll located on a remote server. That dll is a common framework that I want to reference and always have the latest version.

I'm building my template using GAX and NuGet. I could also use T4.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: And what do you already have? What part of the template unfolding is unclear?

Comment: I want to know how I can call a NuGet command (Install-Package) directly at the end of the package execution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do with but will need to write your own Visual Studio Template wizard. When the template wizard is running you can get a IVsPackageInstaller (Found with MEF) and call install package. You can get a list of packages from a folder, config, or just hard code them. This is how MVC 3 tooling update does its pre-installed packages.

Comment: I'd really like to know more about how this is done. I was specifically creating a custom ASP.NET MVC 3.01 (Refresh) template and it breaks because it doesn't have the stuff that the MVC 3.01 project auto-added at original project creation. http://bit.ly/g8LVzd

Comment: @stimpy77 this will become easier in NuGet 1.5. Check out this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/07/08/project-templates-and-preinstalled-nuget-packages.aspx.

Comment: @marcind Yay. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Packages-in-Visual-Studio-Templates